# JavaScript element issue in Twig template with Symfony 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig

I have an issue with Javascript elements in my twig template.

JS carousel element on top of the page is not loading when href path when site menu is changed from a id style reference (e.g href = "#terms") to link to a different page (e.g href={{ path('terms') }}.

This is my part of index.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"/> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <title> {% block title %} Test Script {% endblock %}</title> 
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}"/> 
        {% block stylesheets %} 
            {% stylesheets 'bundles/useruser/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %} 
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css"/> 
            {% endstylesheets %} 
        {% endblock %} 
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
        {% block javascripts %} 
            {% javascripts '@UserUserBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %} 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script> 
            {% endjavascripts %} 
        {% endblock %} 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        {% block body %} 
        <div id="sTop" class="site-main"> 
            <div class="site-header"> 
                <div class="main-header"> 
                    <div class="container"> 
                        <div id="menu-wrapper"> 
                            <div class="row"> 
                                <div class="logo-wrapper col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-8"> 
                                    <h1> 
                                        <a>Travel Flex</a> 
                                    </h1> 
                                </div> 
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-4 main-menu text-left"> 
                                    <ul class="menu-first hidden-sm hidden-xs"> 
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#">{{ 'About' }}</a></li> 
                                        <li><a href="terms">{{ 'Terms & Conditions' }}</a></li> 
                                        <li><a href="privacy">{{ 'Privacy Policy' }}</a></li> 
                                        <li><a href="#contact">{{ 'Subscribe' }}</a></li> 
                                        <li><a href="unsubscribe">{{ 'Unsubscribe' }}</a></li> 
                                    </ul> 
                                    <a href="#" class="toggle-menu visible-sm visible-xs"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a> 
                                </div> 
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="menu-responsive hidden-md hidden-lg"> 
                            <ul> 
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">{{ 'About' }}</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="terms">{{ 'Terms & Conditions' }}</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="privacy">{{ 'Privacy Policy' }}</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#contact">{{ 'Subscribe' }}</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="unsubscribe">{{ 'Unsubscribe' }}</a></li> 
                            </ul> 
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
            <div class="site-slider"> 
                <div class="slider"> 
                    <div class="flexslider"> 
                        <ul class="slides"> 
                            <li> 
                                <div class="overlay"></div> 
                                <img src="{{ asset('bundles/useruser/images/slide1.jpg') }}" alt=""> 
                                <div class="slider-caption visible-md visible-lg"> 
                                    <h2>test text 1</h2> 
                                    <p>test text 1</p> 
                                </div> 
                            </li> 
                            <li> 
                                <div class="overlay"></div> 
                                <img src="{{ asset('bundles/useruser/images/slide2.jpg') }}" alt=""> 
                                <div class="slider-caption visible-md visible-lg"> 
                                    <h2>test text2</h2> 
                                    <p>test text 2</p> 
                                </div> 
                            </li> 
                            <li> 
                                <div class="overlay"></div> 
                                <img src="{{ asset('bundles/useruser/images/slide3.jpg') }}" alt=""> 
                                <div class="slider-caption visible-md visible-lg"> 
                                    <h2>test text 3</h2> 
                                    <p>test text 3</p> 
                                </div> 
                            </li> 
                        </ul> 
                    </div> <!-- /.flexslider --> 
                </div> <!-- /.slider --> 
            </div> <!-- /.site-slider --> 
        </div> <!-- /.site-main -->
```

Carousel element is loading fine when i use href = "#terms".
[image]
However link does not work as it should (links in red rectangular not redirecting to a different page).

When i use href={{ path('terms') }} link works as it should, however carousel element is not loaded.
[image]
Looks like there is an issue with how i include js files into index.html.twig however i am not sure how to fir it. Below is the error from browser console:

[image]

#### Any assistance is appriciated

Comment: Share your jQuery Code for carousel and Add the Screenshot to understand better

Comment: I've amended my original post with screenshots of the issue. First screenshot is when top carousel is working fine however links not working on the top bar. Second carousel - links are working fine but carousel is not loading. Regarding the jQuery code - i am working with the code someone created before me - I can share the whole file because I am not sure which section of it accounts for carousel itself. Thanks

Comment: Looks like the issue is coming from here <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> - this is what the browser console is saying

Comment: add the console error in your question !

Comment: Add your code in http://twigfiddle.com/6hq2s8

Comment: Replace this with <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99027/discussion-between-venkatraman-and-sky21-86).

Answer (score 0):

Replace the Include jQuery Library Code Snippet like below

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Checkout other jQuery CDN or save the file to your server.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Add Absolute URL for your Slider images

```
{{ absolute_url(asset('bundles/useruser/images/slide1.jpg')) }}
```

Comment: thanks but i still have the same issue Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
 throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
};